# Передать данные в другой фрагмент

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-fragment

Вопрос следующего характера:
Есть фрагмент, в котором выполняется цикл for. В данном цикле вызывается новый фрагмент, в который нужно передать шаг цикла for, на котором сработало некое условие, в данном случае была нажата кнопка.
Код выглядит так:

```
for (task in list.withIndex()) {

            button.setOnClickListener {
                 presenter.onBigTaskClick()
            }
}
```

Каким образом я могу в открывшемся фрагменте под названием BigTasFragment получить номер шага цикла for, который был выполнен на предыдущем фрагменте?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете положить данные в Bundle() и передать его в аргументы фрагмента. А во фрагменте извлечь. Хорошей практикой является создавать статический метод в самом фрагменте. Например:

```
companion object {

    private const val YOUR_ARG = "your_args"

    fun createInstance(arg: String) : YourFragment = 
        YourFragment().apply{
            arguments = bundleOf(YOUR_ARG to arg)
        }
}
```

И собственно в активити где вы создаете фрагмент вы его создаете:

```
val fragment = YourFragment.createInstance("Your Args")
```

Получить данные во фрагменте можно так:

```
val arg = requireArguments().getString(YOUR_ARG)
```

Но важно помнить, что Bundle подходит в основном для простых данных. Если вам нужно передавать более сложные объекты то лучше использовать другие способы (например Базу данных или Синглтоны).

Так же этот способ действителен только при создании фрагмента, если вам нужно передавать в уже существующий фрагмент данные, то это делается посредством интерфейсов.